# Delphi 5 DB Aware ComboBox ItemIndex Not Updating

Tags: database, delphi, combobox, delphi-5

So I have a DBAware combobox and my problem is this.

If I do:

```
ComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
```

Then even though visually it shows an item in the combobox being selected, the following still returns true.

```
Query.FieldByName('field').IsNull
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make it so if the field associated with the combobox is null for the record, then I want the combobox to default to the first index. However, when I do this by itemindex it isn't actually making it edit the record.

Any ideas? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting default value to the `ItemIndex` set it in the dataset like

```
Query.Edit;
Query.FieldByName('field').Value := 'Default Value';
Query.Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ItemIndex of a DBComboBox only changes the input field of the DBComboBox.

It does **not** change the data field value of the record.

If you really want to change the field value, via the DBComboBox component.

So you can do it.

```
 [...]
 if ComboBox.Field.IsNull then begin
      ComboBox.Text:=ComboBox.Items[0];
      Query.Edit;
      ComboBox.Field.AsString:=ComboBox.Items[0];
      Query.Post;
 end;
 [...]
```